# Limit the number of elements appended to array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, stream, limit

I have a stream from an API that constantly updates the price.  the goal is to compare the last two prices and if x > Y then do something.  I can get the prices into an array, however, the array grows very large very quick..  How can I limit the number of elements to 2, then compare them?

My code:

```
def stream_to_queue(self):
        response = self.connect_to_stream()
        if response.status_code != 200:
            return   
        prices = []    
        for line in response.iter_lines(1):
            if line:
                try:
                    msg = json.loads(line)
                except Exception as e:
                    print "Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e)
                    return
                if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
                    price = msg["tick"]["ask"]
                    prices.append(price)

        print prices
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if msg.has_key("instrument") or msg.has_key("tick"):
    price = msg["tick"]["ask"]
    last_price = None
    if prices:
        last_price = prices[-1]
        prices = [last_price]
        if last_price > price:
            #do stuff
    prices.append(price)
```

Comment: Thats awesome, I think this should do it!  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help :)

Comment: The logic is unclear. @padraic-cunningham solution is perfect for this kinda problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with `maxlen` set to 2:

```
from collections import deque

deq = deque(maxlen=2)
```

You could also manually check the size and rearrange:

```
if len(arr) == 2:
    arr[0], arr[1] = arr[1], new_value
```

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) is some more documentation on `deque` in case you didn't know about it.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this is what I needed.